# ¿Como llamar un procedimiento almacenado de Oracle desde C#?

Tags: c#, oracle, .net, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado que recibe como único parámetro de entrada **RUT** que es de tipo **varchar2**. este procedimiento tiene el trabajo de insertar datos (entre ellos una imagen) en una tabla temporal que elimina los datos al hacer **commit**.

Desde .NET tengo que introducir el parametro **RUT** y ejecutar el procedimiento.

Tengo Visual Studio 2019 y Oracle 11g uno de 32bits y otro de 64bits.

```
public static void llamarProceInfo( string rut)
{

    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion"].ConnectionString))
    {
        OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "PS_OBT_POSTULANTE";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add("P_RUT_POSTULANTE", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = rut;
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Excepcion Base de Datos Oracle: {0}", ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

El procedimiento no tiene ningún problema ya lo he probado desde Oracle, pero al ejecutarlo desde C#, no se insertan los datos en la tabla.

¿Alguna idea?

Adjunto codigo del proceso.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PS_OBT_POSTULANTE (P_RUT_POSTULANTE IN VARCHAR2)
IS
    V_TEMP_BLOB BLOB;
    V_TEMP_BFILE BFILE;
    V_EXISTE NUMBER(2);
    V_FOTO VARCHAR(50);

    --VARIABLES TABLA
    V_NUM_FOLIO NUMBER(10,0);
    V_FECHA_POSTULACION DATE;
    V_NOMBRE_RECEPTOR VARCHAR2(150 BYTE);
    V_RUT_PST VARCHAR2(50 BYTE);
    V_NOMBRE_PST VARCHAR2(150 BYTE);
    V_FECHA_NAC_PST DATE;
    V_NACIONALIDAD_PST VARCHAR2(50 BYTE);
    V_ESTADO_CIVIL_PST VARCHAR2(50 BYTE);
    V_TOTAL_CARGA_FAM_PST NUMBER(2,0);
    V_PUEBLO_IND_ORIG VARCHAR2(100 BYTE);
    V_TITULO_PST VARCHAR2(100 BYTE);
    V_RUT_CONYU VARCHAR2(50 BYTE);
    V_NOMBRE_CONYU VARCHAR2(150 BYTE);
    V_CALLE_DIR_PST VARCHAR2(150 BYTE);
    V_NUM_HOGAR NUMBER(8,0);
    V_BLOCK_NUM_PST NUMBER(8,0);
    V_DEPTO_NUM_PST NUMBER(8,0); 
    V_MANZANA_PST VARCHAR2(50 BYTE);
    V_SITIO_PST VARCHAR2(50 BYTE);
    V_REGION_PST VARCHAR2(150 BYTE);
    V_COMUNA_PST VARCHAR2(150 BYTE);
    V_FONO_TRAB_PST NUMBER(15,0);
    V_FONO_DOM_PST NUMBER(15,0);
    V_FONO_MOVIL_PST NUMBER(15,0);
    V_COD_POSTA_PST NUMBER(20,0);
    V_EMAIL_PST VARCHAR2(50 BYTE);
    V_TRAMO VARCHAR2(20 BYTE);
    V_REGION_VIV VARCHAR2(150 BYTE);
    V_COMUNA_VIV VARCHAR2(150 BYTE);
    V_TIPO_VIV VARCHAR2(20 BYTE);
    V_VALOR_VIV VARCHAR2(30 BYTE); 
    V_AHORRO_PST VARCHAR2(30 BYTE);
    V_PUNTAJE_MIN NUMBER(5,0);
    V_PUNTAJE_OBT_PST NUMBER(5,0);

BEGIN

    --- CARGAR IMAGEN
    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(V_TEMP_BLOB,TRUE);
    V_FOTO := P_RUT_POSTULANTE || '.PNG';
    V_TEMP_BFILE := BFILENAME('DIR_LOB',V_FOTO);
    V_EXISTE := dbms_lob.fileexists(V_TEMP_BFILE);

    --VERIFICAR SI EXISTE EN EL DIRECTORIO
    IF V_EXISTE = 1 THEN
        -- ABRIR IMAGEN
        DBMS_LOB.FILEOPEN(V_TEMP_BFILE, DBMS_LOB.FILE_READONLY);
        DBMS_LOB.LOADFROMFILE(V_TEMP_BLOB,V_TEMP_BFILE, SYS.DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(V_TEMP_BFILE));

        -- INSERTAR VALORES A VARIABLES
        SELECT POSTN.FOLIO_N,
             POSTN.FEC_RECEPCION,
             REC.NOMBRE "NOMBRE_REC",
             POS.NUMRUT||'-'||POS.DVRUT "RUT_PST",
             POS.NOMBRES||' '||POS.APELLIDO_PAT||' '||POS.APELLIDO_MAT "NOMBRE_PST",
             POS.FECNAC,
             POS.NACIONALIDAD,
             pkg_puntaje.FN_DESCR_EST_CIVIL(POS.ID_POSTULANTE) "ESTADO_CIVIL",
             PKG_PUNTAJE.FN_TOTAL_CARGAS(POS.ID_POSTULANTE)"TOTAL_CARGAS",
             PIO.DESCRIPCION "PUEBLO_ORIG",
             TIT.NOMBRE "TITULO",
             COY.RUT "RUT_CONYU",
             COY.NOMBRE "NOMBRE_CONYU",
             POS.DIR_CALLE,
             POS.DIR_NUMERO,
             POS.DIR_BLOCK,
             POS.DIR_DEPARTAMENTO,
             POS.DIR_MANZANA,
             POS.DIR_SITIO,
             REG.NOMBRE "REGION",
             COU.NOMBRE "COMUNA",
             POS.FONO_TRABAJO,
             POS.FONO_DOMICILIO,
             POS.CELULAR,
             POS.COD_POSTAL,
             POS.EMAIL,
             TRP.TITULO "TRAMO",
             DIRVIV.REGION "REGION_VIV",
             DIRVIV.COMUNA "COMUNA_VIV",
             INFOTEC.TIPO_VIVIENDA,
             FN_VALOR_FORMATO(UBI.VALOR),
             FN_VALOR_FORMATO(AHO.MONTO_AHORRO),
             FN_PUNTAJE_MIN, -- CAMBIAR Y PONER LA DE LA IRINA
             PP.TOTAL
             INTO
                V_NUM_FOLIO, V_FECHA_POSTULACION, 
                V_NOMBRE_RECEPTOR, V_RUT_PST, 
                V_NOMBRE_PST, V_FECHA_NAC_PST,
                V_NACIONALIDAD_PST, V_ESTADO_CIVIL_PST, 
                V_TOTAL_CARGA_FAM_PST, V_PUEBLO_IND_ORIG, 
                V_TITULO_PST, V_RUT_CONYU,
                V_NOMBRE_CONYU, V_CALLE_DIR_PST, 
                V_NUM_HOGAR, V_BLOCK_NUM_PST, 
                V_DEPTO_NUM_PST, V_MANZANA_PST,
                V_SITIO_PST, V_REGION_PST,
                V_COMUNA_PST, V_FONO_TRAB_PST, 
                V_FONO_DOM_PST, V_FONO_MOVIL_PST,
                V_COD_POSTA_PST, V_EMAIL_PST, 
                V_TRAMO, V_REGION_VIV , 
                V_COMUNA_VIV, V_TIPO_VIV,
                V_VALOR_VIV, V_AHORRO_PST,
                V_PUNTAJE_MIN, V_PUNTAJE_OBT_PST
            FROM POSTULANTE POS LEFT JOIN POSTULACION POSTN
                ON POS.ID_POSTULANTE = postn.id_postulante
            LEFT JOIN RECEPTOR REC
                ON POSTN.ID_RECEPTOR = rec.id_receptor
            LEFT JOIN PUEBLO_INDIGENA_ORIGINARIO PIO
                ON pos.id_pueborig = PIO.ID_PUEBORIG
            LEFT JOIN TITULO TIT
                ON POS.ID_POSTULANTE = tit.id_postulante
            LEFT JOIN CONYUGE COY
                ON pos.id_postulante = COY.ID_POSTULANTE
            LEFT JOIN REGION REG
                ON POS.ID_REGION = reg.id_region
            INNER JOIN COMUNA COU
                ON POS.ID_COMUNA = COU.ID_COMUNA
            LEFT JOIN UBICACION_Y_PREFERENCIA UBI
                ON POS.ID_POSTULANTE = ubi.id_postulante
            LEFT JOIN TRAMO_POSTULACION TRP
                ON ubi.id_tramos = TRP.ID_TRAMOS
            -- SUB CONSULTA PARA NO CONFUNDIR CON LA REGION Y COMUNA DEL POSTULANTE
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT VIV.ID_VIVIENDA "ID_VIVIENDA", 
                        PT.ID_POSTULACION "ID_POSTULACION",
                        RG.NOMBRE "REGION", 
                        CM.NOMBRE "COMUNA" 
                    FROM VIVIENDA VIV 
                    JOIN REGION RG 
                        ON VIV.ID_REGION = RG.ID_REGION
                    JOIN POSTULACION PT
                        ON VIV.ID_VIVIENDA = PT.VIVIENDA_ELEGIDA
                    RIGHT JOIN POSTULANTE PTT
                        ON PT.ID_POSTULANTE = PTT.ID_POSTULANTE
                    JOIN COMUNA CM 
                        ON PTT.ID_POSTULANTE = CM.ID_REGION
                    WHERE PTT.NUMRUT = P_RUT_POSTULANTE
                    ) DIRVIV
                ON POSTN.ID_POSTULACION = DIRVIV.ID_POSTULACION
            LEFT JOIN INFORME_TEC_HABITABILIDAD INFOTEC
                ON POSTN.VIVIENDA_ELEGIDA = INFOTEC.ID_VIVIENDA
            LEFT JOIN CUENTA_AHORRO AHO
                ON pos.id_postulante = AHO.ID_POSTULANTE
            LEFT JOIN PUNTAJE_POSTULANTE PP
                ON POS.ID_POSTULANTE = PP.ID_POSTULANTE
            WHERE POS.NUMRUT = P_RUT_POSTULANTE;

        -- INSERTAR VARIABLES JUNTO CON LA IMAGEN A LA TABLA TEMPORAL
        INSERT INTO TEMP_PST VALUES (
            V_NUM_FOLIO, V_TEMP_BLOB,V_FECHA_POSTULACION, 
            V_NOMBRE_RECEPTOR, V_RUT_PST, 
            V_NOMBRE_PST, V_FECHA_NAC_PST,
            V_NACIONALIDAD_PST, V_ESTADO_CIVIL_PST, 
            V_TOTAL_CARGA_FAM_PST, V_PUEBLO_IND_ORIG, 
            V_TITULO_PST, V_RUT_CONYU,
            V_NOMBRE_CONYU, V_CALLE_DIR_PST, 
            V_NUM_HOGAR, V_BLOCK_NUM_PST, 
            V_DEPTO_NUM_PST, V_MANZANA_PST,
            V_SITIO_PST, V_REGION_PST,
            V_COMUNA_PST, V_FONO_TRAB_PST, 
            V_FONO_DOM_PST, V_FONO_MOVIL_PST,
            V_COD_POSTA_PST, V_EMAIL_PST, 
            V_TRAMO, V_REGION_VIV , 
            V_COMUNA_VIV, V_TIPO_VIV,
            V_VALOR_VIV, V_AHORRO_PST,
            V_PUNTAJE_MIN, V_PUNTAJE_OBT_PST
        );
        -- CERRAR IMAGEN
        DBMS_LOB.FILECLOSE(V_TEMP_BFILE);
    END IF;
    -- LIBERAR RECURSOS
    dbms_lob.freetemporary(V_TEMP_BLOB);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Error al realizar el procedimiento SP_OBT_POSTULANTE');
END PS_OBT_POSTULANTE;
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el paquete del procedimiento almacenado? así podemos ver la definición de campos y si falto algo más, además de la excepción que te da que viene muy bien para saber por donde van los tiros

Comment: @JuanRu
Es algo extenso el proceso les deje editado el post con el proceso.
Desde ya, muchas gracias por responder.

Comment: gracias por dejar el procedimiento almacenado ¿puedes poner también la excepción que te da? intentaré contestarte pero me temo que hasta el lunes no puedo hacerlo con la extensión que se merece el tema

Comment: @JuanRu no me da ninguna excepción. Ese es el problema, según parece que se ejecuta correctamente pero no se ejecuta el proceso en sí, me refiero a que no se insertan los datos a la tabla. En Oracle lo ejecuto y se insertan los datos a la tabla. A lo que llegue del trabajo puedo enviar imágenes del resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pablo estás utilizando un "adaptador de datos" (`OracleDataAdapter`) para lanzar un procedimiento almacenado cuando en realidad éste se utiliza para tareas CRUD (insercción, lectura, actualización y eliminación) que tiene un tipo de comando para cada operación, ya que tiene en cuenta el estado de las filas y lanza una sentencia en medida de ellas.

Lo correcto es que uses un `OracleCommand` y lances la sentencia de la forma más conveniente:

- `ExecuteNonQuery`: cuando la sentencia es insert, update o delete devolviendo el número de filas afectadas.
- `ExecuteScalar`: cuando quieres que la setencia devuelva un único valor, la primera columna de la primera fila.
- `ExecuteReader`: para lanzar una sentencia de consulta de datos, se usa en conjunto a OracleDataReader

En tu caso, por eso te pedía el procedimiento almacenado, es una inserción y por lo tanto usarías `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Por si te sirve de modelo te paso cómo haría yo la codificación, le incluyo `BindByName` para que no dependa del orden de inserción de los parámetros, que tendrían que ser el mismo que en el procedimiento almacenado, y los enlace por el nombre, de esta forma si te equivocas en el orden de insercción no te vuelves loco:

```
public void LanzarNonQuery(string cadenaConex, Parametros parametros)
{
    // Se utiliza la instrucción using para asegurarnos la desctrucción de los objetos y liberar recursos
    using (var con = new OracleConnection(cadenaConex))
    {
        try
        {
            // Se abre la conexión
            con.Open();

            using (var com = new OracleCommand())
            {
                // Al comando se le asigna la conexión
                com.Connection = con;

                // Se le indica el tipo de comando y el nombre
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.CommandText = "NombrePaquete.NombreProcedimientoAlmacenado";
                com.BindByName = true;

                // Se añaden los parámetros de entrada
                OracleParameter param1 = cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("PARAM1", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Input));
                param1.Value = parametros.valor1 != null ? (object)Convert.ToDecimal(document.Required.Value): DBNull.Value;
                OracleParameter param2 = cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("PARAM2", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Input));
                param2.Value = !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(parametros.valor2)) ? (object)parametros.valor2: DBNull.Value;

                // Se ejecuta el procedimiento y se comprueba la salida
                var registrosAfectados = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR : " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Nos aseguramos de cerrar la conexión en caso de error
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Pero además viendo tu procedimiento almacenado donde normalmente tenemos más problemas es en no equivocarnos en la definición y asignación de parámetros. Esto lo soluciono en parte mediante el uso de una plantilla que genera código de forma automática y que se llaman plantillas T4. Te dejo la que yo uso por si te viene bien. Hay que incluirlo en el proyecto y le cambias las variables `cadenaConexion`, `paqueteOracle` y `procedimientoOracle`, lo lanzas y te genera un fichero de texto con todos los parámetros del procedimiento almacenado listos para insertarlos en el código. Además enlaza la librería de `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` a la ruta donde la tengas tú almacenada en tu equipo.

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\LibreríasExternas\OracleDlls\Oracle.DataAccess.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<#
// Cadena de conexión con BBDD
string cadenaConexion = "user id=tuUsuario;password=tuPassword;data source=TUESQUEMA;";
// Paquete de Oracle con el Procedimiento
string paqueteOracle = "NOMBRE_PAQUETE";
// Procedimiento almacenado con los parámetros a extraer
string procedimientoOracle = "NOMBRE_PROCEDIMIENTO";

string resultado = "Todo OK";

OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(cadenaConexion);
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
try
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = paqueteOracle + "." + procedimientoOracle;
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
    StringBuilder strBld = new StringBuilder();
    strBld.AppendLine("Nombre\tTipo\tDirección\tLongitud");

#>
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("<#=cmd.CommandText#>", conexion);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.BindByName = true;

<#

    foreach (OracleParameter parametro in cmd.Parameters)
    {
        strBld.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", parametro.ParameterName, parametro.OracleDbType, parametro.Direction, parametro.Size));
#>
<#
        if(parametro.Direction == ParameterDirection.Output)
        {
#>
    OracleParameter <#=parametro.ParameterName#> = cmd.Parameters.Add("<#=parametro.ParameterName#>", OracleDbType.<#=parametro.OracleDbType#>, <#=parametro.Size#>, DBNull.Value, ParameterDirection.<#=parametro.Direction#>);
<#
        }
        else
        {
#>
    OracleParameter <#=parametro.ParameterName#> = cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("<#=parametro.ParameterName#>", OracleDbType.<#=parametro.OracleDbType#>, ParameterDirection.<#=parametro.Direction#>));
    // TODO : Completar la asignación del valor al parámetro
    <#=parametro.ParameterName#>.Value = DBNull.Value;

<#
        }
    }
#>

RESUMEN
<#=strBld.ToString()#>
<#
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    resultado = "ERROR : " + ex.Message;
}
finally
{
    if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        cmd.Connection.Close();
#>Conexión con BBDD cerrada correctamente...
<#
    }
}
#>Finalizado <#=resultado#><#
#>
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola, eso de las plantillas T4 no lo había escuchado, están buenísimas gracias por el dato y la plantilla.
Recién acabo de probarlo con el `executeNonQuery()` y aun así,  no se insertan los datos a la tabla.
Ahora que lo pienso, al momento de hacer el `executeNonQuery()`, ¿Es probable que ocurra una confirmación durante ese método?, lo pienso por la tabla que es temporal y una confirmación eliminaría las filas.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con lo de "confirmación"? Cuando se lanza el `ExecuteNonQuery` llama directamente al procedimiento almacenado, si te refieres a una transacción, en el código que te hemos dejado de ejemplo no está añadida la transacción por lo que no debería de influir y ejecutarlo tal cual. No te va a quedar otra que ir viendo los valores que has ido añadiendo en los parámetros y con esos mismos lanzar el procedimiento desde Oracle para poder depurarlo o meter un parámetro de salida que te indique hasta donde llega. Por cierto ¿se sigue ejecutando sin devolver ninguna excepción?

Comment: Con confirmación me refiero aun `commit`, pero por lo que estube leyendo, ese es otra funcion del `OracleCommand`. Si, se sigue ejecutando sin devolver ninguna excepción.

Comment: Efectivamente el `commit` se hace durante una transacción pero en este caso al estar llamado a un único procedimiento almacenado no tiene mucho sentido. Para ello se llama al método `BeginTransaction` de la conexión y el objeto `OracleTransaccion` se le iría pasando a los diferentes `OracleCommand` para finalizarla con el `Commit`, pero ya te digo que en este caso no tiene nada que ver. Prueba a meter un parámetro de salida que te vaya indicando por dónde va pasando y que te de pistas de lo que hace.

Comment: Gracias por seguir el post, por ahora encontré una solución, sucede que los datos que inserta es a la tabla temporal, probé cambiando esa tabla por una normal y se ejecuto sin problemas, inserta todo. ¿Tienes alguna idea por que no deja con la tabla temporal?

Answer (score 0):

No estas ejecutando el procedure

Para hacerlo deberias utilizar el

```
comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

y esa linea no la tienes en el codigo que nos muestras.

No se usa el `OracleDataAdapter` para ejecutar un procedure que realiza un insert, este aplicaria si vas a obtener los datos de un select

El codigo deberia lucir como esto

```
public static void llamarProceInfo( string rut)
{
    try
    {
        string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion"].ConnectionString;
        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connstring))
        {
            connection.Open();

            OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("PS_OBT_POSTULANTE", connection);

            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add("P_RUT_POSTULANTE", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = rut;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Excepcion Base de Datos Oracle: {0}", ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Ademas un detalle, si falla puede que falte indicar el `schema` junto al nombre del procedure, osea

```
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("<schema>.PS_OBT_POSTULANTE", connection);
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. Acabo de hacer lo que me has dicho y si, ahí cometí un error con lo del `DataAdapter` gracias por corregir, pero el problema persiste, aun no se insertan los datos a la tabla, y si trate con ponerle el `schema`.

Comment: Al usar el ExecuteNonQuery() este deberia invocar al procedure cosa que antes no hacia, con lo cual sino lo hace deberias tener un mensaje de error

Comment: Si use el ExecuteNonQuery(), aun asi, la tabla sigue vacía y no tira ninguna excepción. ¿Se puede poner un procedimiento dentro de una funcion?, talvez, si llamo a una funcion atraves de un SELECT con el procedimiento dentro, se ejecute.

Comment: que pasa si quitas el `IF V_EXISTE = 1 THEN` en el procedure? crea un procedure simple que inserte sin tantas validaciones, asi sabras qu se invoca

Comment: lo intentaré, por ahora encontré una solución, y esque el problema(creo yo) lo da por la tabla temporal. Probé insertando los datos a una tabla normal y se ejecuto sin problemas, aunque no era lo que quería. ¿Sabes porque ocurre?

Comment: la verdad es que nunca utilice tablas temporales en oracle

Comment: Si, yo tampoco jaja. Pero quería probarlas. Gracias de todas maneras. Saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude realizar.
Al parecer la tabla temporal no deja insertar datos desde un procedimiento almacenado llamado desde C#.
Tuve que eliminar esa tabla y crear una nueva (normal) y ahí se pudo realizar correctamente el procedimiento desde C#.

Realmente no es lo que quería, ya que la idea era que se borraran los datos de la tabla fácilmente, pero es la manera que me deja ejecutar el procedimiento.

Gracias por estar atentos al post, se agradece un montón.

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/162621)

Comment: No me había dado cuenta, gracias